# hadoopy.launch_frozen Cannot execute script

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoopy

I'm running the command hadoopy.launch_frozen.

When I run my script, this error appears:

```
File "Task.py", line 22, in <module>
    hadoopy.launch_frozen(data_path, output_path, 'Main.py', temp_path=tmp_path)
  File "/home/aflores/code/pemex/src/src/hadoopy/hadoopy/_runner.py", line 407, in launch_frozen
    make_executable=False, **kw)
  File "/home/aflores/code/pemex/src/src/hadoopy/hadoopy/_runner.py", line 179, in launch
    script_info = _parse_info(script_path, python_cmd)
  File "/home/aflores/code/pemex/src/src/hadoopy/hadoopy/_runner.py", line 81, in _parse_info
    raise ValueError('Cannot execute script [%s]!  Script output below...\nstdout\n%s\nstderr\n%s' % (script_path, stdout, stderr))
ValueError: Cannot execute script [Main.py]!  Script output below...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reinstalled all with my user as administrator and the error dissapeared.